# Creating Writes[T] for Custom Object

Tags: json, scala, playframework

[Play for Scala](http://www.manning.com/hilton/) shows how to convert JSON to a Scala object.

```
case class Product(ean: Long, name: String, description: String)

    import play.api.libs.json._
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

    implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = (
      (JsPath \ "ean").write[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
    )(unlift(Product.unapply))
```

And then using in REPL:

```
scala> val p = Product(100, "tilley hat", "Nice hat")
p: Product = Product(100,tilley hat,Nice hat)

scala> Json.toJson(p)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"ean":100,"name":"tilley hat",
                                             "description":"Nice hat"}
```

What's going on with the last line: `(unlift(Product.unapply))` of the `Writes[Product]`?

Comment: Note that you'll get the same `Writes` with `implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = Json.writes[Product]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Product.unapply _` is a function `Product => Option[(Long, String, String)]`.

Result type of this expression:

```
(
  (JsPath \ "ean").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
)
```

is `FunctionalBuilder[OWrites]#CanBuild3[Long,String,String]`. It accepts `T => (Long, String, String)` as parameter of method `apply`.

So you have to convert `Product => Option[(Long, String, String)]` to `Product => (Long, String, String)`.

Method `unlift` accepts `T => Option[R]` and returns `T => R`. Unlifted function throws `MatchError` instead of `None`. It produces something like this:

```
val unlifted = (Product.unapply _) andThen { case Some(r) => r }
```

Default `unapply` method for case class should never return `None`, so for case class `unlift` is safe.

Comment: could you please look at this question too- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964407/implicit-resolution-in-play-framework-json-library? thank you