# Creating Reads for List[case class]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have 3 case classes:

```
scala> case class Friend(id: Long, hobbies: List[Long])
defined class Friend

scala> case class Kid(friends: List[Friend])
defined class Kid

scala> case class Parent(kids: List[Kid])
defined class Parent
```

They can be shown through a hierarchy (Parent has Kid(s) has Friend(s) has (id and hobbies).

```
Parent   
   ---> Kid
      ---> Friend
           ---> id: Long
           ---> hobbies: List[Long]
```

I created the `FriendsReads` (even though, as [senia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406435/senia) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611710/creating-writest-for-custom-object#comment32657936_21611710), I could've just used

```
scala> implicit val FriendReads: Reads[Friend] = Json.format[Friend]
FriendReads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Friend] = play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1@236b2692

scala> implicit val FriendReads: Reads[Friend] = (
     |   (JsPath \ "id").read[Long] and
     |    (JsPath \ "hobbies").read[List[Long]]
     | )(Friend.apply _)
FriendReads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Friend] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8@4bb7bb4
```

Then, when I tried to create the `KidReads`, I ran into a compile-time problem.

```
scala> implicit val KidReads: Reads[Kid] = (
     |   (JsPath \ "friends").read[List[Friend]]
     | )(Kid.apply _)
<console>:40: error: overloaded method value read with alternatives:
  (t: List[Friend])play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Friend]] <and>
  (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Friend]])play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Friend]]
 cannot be applied to (List[Friend] => Kid)
         (JsPath \ "friends").read[List[Friend]]
                              ^
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Thanks, Travis, you're right. I saw a new type and forgot to check your helpful answer. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `(JsPath \ "friends").read[List[Friend]]` creates `Reads[List[Friend]]`, you could convert it to `Reads[Kid]` using `map` method like this:

```
implicit val KidReads: Reads[Kid] =
  (JsPath \ "friends").read[List[Friend]] map Kid.apply
```

Function `Kid.apply` will be applied to result of `Reads[List[Friend]]#reads` like this:

```
val friendListReads: Reads[List[Friend]] = (JsPath \ "friends").read[List[Friend]]

implicit val kidReads: Reads[Kid] = new Reads[Kid] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Kid] = friendListReads.reads(json) match {
    case JsSuccess(fList, path) = JsSuccess(Kid(fList), path)
    case e: JsError => e
  }
}
```

Comment: When mapping over Reads[List[Friend]], map's function f has signature: List[Friend] -> Friend?

Comment: I'm having trouble reasoning about this map function. Why does applying Kid.map to each Friend work?

Comment: thank you. If `Friend`'s second field changed to `case class Friend(id: Long, hobbies: List[SomeObject])`, would I then need to define a `Reads[SomeObject]`? I'm trying to get a grip on when it's necessary to define a `Reads` or `Writes`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Yes, you have to define `Reads` for all classes you want to read from json.