# Implicit Resolution in Play Framework JSON Library

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

Working with the Play Framework's JSON Library, I'm creating a `Format[T]` for some class T.

```
val a: JsPath = (JsPath \ "age")
val b: Format[Int] = (JsPath \ "age").format[Int]
val x: FunctionalBuilder[OFormat]#CanBuild2[Int, String] = ( 
           (JsPath \ "age").format[Int] and 
           (JsPath \ "location").format[String]
       )
```

Looking at the explicit types, we see that (in `x`) calling `Format[Int] and Format[String]` returns a type of `FunctionalBuilder[OFormat]#CanBuild2[Int, String]`.

How does this conversion occur in the Play Framework JSON Library source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax and meaning of a Scala/Play! code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990812/syntax-and-meaning-of-a-scala-play-code-sample)

Comment: try `val r1 = (JsPath \ "age").format[Int]`; `val r2 = (JsPath \ "location").format[String]`; `import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}`; `u.show{ u.reify{ r1 and r2 }.tree }`.

Comment: thanks, @senia. I voted to close given that you already answered it at the above link.